# How to use Entry for text display and edit in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, crud, edit

I have account info page. When user click edit I want to allow them to edit their info.

[image: x]

But I dont want user to travel to another page because it would be exactly the same page but only with editable fields. Can I reuse existing page for editing somehow? I tried changing fields type to Entry but it just gives input field and doesnt show info. Or shoud I create new page for editing?

When I use label it shows normally, like in a scrrenshot above:

```
 <Label x:Name ="patientPhone"/>
```

But I cannot edit Label. I must use Entry?

I try to use Entry with isenabled false but it shows only one digit (out of full phone number):
[image]

Code with entry:

```
<Entry x:Name ="patientPhone" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  IsEnabled="false" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you determine what might be wrong

Comment: You can switch between IsReadonly and/or IsEnabled on button press (true|false).

Comment: @spzvtbg it doesnt work, I addded to question.

Comment: you need to specify a `WidthRequest` value, or make it fill its container by changing the `HorizontalOptions`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Entry` to achieve this and set `IsEnabled` for it. And for your layout, it is recommended that you use `Grid` to do this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"> 

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label  Text="Address:"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center"  />

        <Entry x:Name ="patientAddress"  Text="address 1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow"   IsEnabled="false" />

        <Label  Text="Phone:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Entry x:Name ="patientPhone" Text="address 2"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"    BackgroundColor="Yellow"  IsEnabled="false" />
    </Grid>

    <Button Text="Edit" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

</StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            patientAddress.IsEnabled = true; 
            patientPhone.IsEnabled = true;  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query, I give the solution shown below.

Xaml Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestDemoStack.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"  />
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label  Text="Address:"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center"  />

            <Label x:Name="patientAddressLabel" Text="Your Address"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Center"  />

            <Entry x:Name ="patientAddressEntry"  Text="Your Address" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow"   IsVisible="false" />

            <Label  Text="Phone:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="patientPhoneLabel" Text="123456789" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Entry x:Name ="patientPhoneEntry" Text="123456789"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"    BackgroundColor="Yellow"  IsVisible="false" />
        </Grid>

        <Button x:Name="btn_click" Text="Edit" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Please add this code in Xaml.cs class file for the manage button click even.

Xaml.cs Class File Code:-

```
namespace TestDemoStack
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        bool isViewEditable = true;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(isViewEditable == true)
        {
            isViewEditable = false;
            patientAddressEntry.Text = patientAddressLabel.Text;
            patientPhoneEntry.Text = patientPhoneLabel.Text;

            patientAddressEntry.IsVisible = true;
            patientPhoneEntry.IsVisible = true;

            patientAddressLabel.IsVisible = false;
            patientPhoneLabel.IsVisible = false;

            btn_click.Text = "Save";
        }
        else
        {
            isViewEditable = true;

            patientAddressEntry.IsVisible = false;
            patientPhoneEntry.IsVisible = false;

            patientAddressLabel.Text = patientAddressEntry.Text;
            patientPhoneLabel.Text = patientPhoneEntry.Text;

            patientAddressLabel.IsVisible = true;
            patientPhoneLabel.IsVisible = true;

            btn_click.Text = "Edit";
        }
        
    }
    }
}
```

I think this solution is helpful to you.

Thank you.